# stop and run again an application in erlang

Tags: erlang

have an application developed in Erlang and to run this application I need to do: **./build.sh && ./deploy.sh && ./erl_start.sh**

I want to make a function  that will do the same thing as **Ctrl + C**  and run   **./build.sh && ./deploy.sh && ./erl_start.sh**

**meaning stop the application and run again this application**

I try with this function :

```
verify(Val)->
    if Val =:=40 ->
Pid = self(), 

io:format("~w~n",[Pid]),
spawn(fun() -> exit(Pid, kill) end),
    LsOut = os:cmd("./build.sh && ./deploy.sh && ./erl_start.sh");

    true -> ok

    end.
```

and when I test this function I have this error :

```
1> model:verify(40).
<0.144.0>
** exception exit: killed
```

I test this command  :

```
1> [io:format("~p : ~p~n",[Pid,erlang:process_info(Pid,current_function)]) || Pid <- processes()].
<0.0.0> : {current_function,{init,loop,1}}
<0.3.0> : {current_function,{erl_prim_loader,loop,3}}
<0.5.0> : {current_function,{gen_event,fetch_msg,5}}
<0.6.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.8.0> : {current_function,{application_master,main_loop,2}}
<0.9.0> : {current_function,{application_master,loop_it,4}}
<0.10.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.11.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.12.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.13.0> : {current_function,{global,loop_the_locker,1}}
<0.14.0> : {current_function,{global,collect_deletions,2}}
<0.15.0> : {current_function,{global,loop_the_registrar,0}}
<0.16.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.18.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.19.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.20.0> : {current_function,{code_server,loop,1}}
<0.21.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.22.0> : {current_function,{standard_error,server_loop,1}}
<0.23.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.24.0> : {current_function,{user_drv,server_loop,5}}
<0.25.0> : {current_function,{group,server_loop,3}}
<0.26.0> : {current_function,{group,server_loop,3}}
<0.27.0> : {current_function,{shell,shell_rep,4}}
<0.28.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.29.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.36.0> : {current_function,{application_master,main_loop,2}}
<0.37.0> : {current_function,{application_master,loop_it,4}}
<0.38.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.39.0> : {current_function,{gen_event,fetch_msg,5}}
<0.40.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.41.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.44.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.45.0> : {current_function,{mnesia_locker,loop,1}}
<0.46.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.47.0> : {current_function,{mnesia_tm,doit_loop,1}}
<0.48.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.49.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.53.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.54.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.63.0> : {current_function,{disk_log,loop,1}}
<0.65.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.66.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.67.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.68.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.69.0> : {current_function,{mnesia_late_loader,loop,1}}
<0.105.0> : {current_function,{application_master,main_loop,2}}
<0.106.0> : {current_function,{application_master,loop_it,4}}
<0.107.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.108.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.109.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.110.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.111.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.112.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.113.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.114.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.115.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.117.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.118.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.119.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.120.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.121.0> : {current_function,{prim_inet,accept0,2}}
<0.123.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.124.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.125.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.126.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.127.0> : {current_function,{prim_inet,accept0,2}}
<0.129.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.130.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.131.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.132.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.133.0> : {current_function,{prim_inet,accept0,2}}
<0.135.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.136.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.137.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.138.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.139.0> : {current_function,{prim_inet,accept0,2}}
<0.140.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.143.0> : {current_function,{os,start_port_srv_loop,2}}
<0.144.0> : {current_function,{erl_eval,do_apply,5}}
[ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,
 ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok|...]
```

and also I test this command :

```
1> [io:format("~p : ~p~n",[Pid,erlang:process_info(Pid,initial_call)]) || Pid <- processes()]. 
<0.0.0> : {initial_call,{otp_ring0,start,2}}
<0.3.0> : {initial_call,{erlang,apply,2}}
<0.5.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.6.0> : {initial_call,{erlang,apply,2}}
<0.8.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.9.0> : {initial_call,{application_master,start_it,4}}
<0.10.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.11.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.12.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.13.0> : {initial_call,{erlang,apply,2}}
<0.14.0> : {initial_call,{erlang,apply,2}}
<0.15.0> : {initial_call,{erlang,apply,2}}
<0.16.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.18.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.19.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.20.0> : {initial_call,{erlang,apply,2}}
<0.21.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.22.0> : {initial_call,{standard_error,server,2}}
<0.23.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.24.0> : {initial_call,{user_drv,server,2}}
<0.25.0> : {initial_call,{group,server,3}}
<0.26.0> : {initial_call,{group,server,3}}
<0.27.0> : {initial_call,{erlang,apply,2}}
<0.28.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.29.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.36.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.37.0> : {initial_call,{application_master,start_it,4}}
<0.38.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.39.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.40.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.41.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.44.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.45.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.46.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.47.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.48.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.49.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.53.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.54.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.63.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.65.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.66.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.67.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.68.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.69.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.105.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.106.0> : {initial_call,{application_master,start_it,4}}
<0.107.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.108.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.109.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.110.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.111.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.112.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.113.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.114.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.115.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.117.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.118.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.119.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.120.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.121.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.123.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.124.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.125.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.126.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.127.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.129.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.130.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.131.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.132.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.133.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.135.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.136.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.137.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.138.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.139.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.140.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.143.0> : {initial_call,{erlang,apply,2}}
<0.144.0> : {initial_call,{erlang,apply,2}}
[ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,
 ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok|...]
```

I try with this function :

```
verify(Val) ->
    erlang:halt();

verify(_) ->
    % do nothing

   ok.
```

and when I test I have this result :

```
1>  model:verify(40).
root@ubuntu:/home/afif/Desktop/ttest/erlang#
```

it only  exit the VM

but as I already said I want to **stop the application and run again this application**

and for this I try with :

```
verify(Val) ->
        erlang:halt(),
    LsOut = os:cmd("./build.sh && ./deploy.sh && ./erl_start.sh");
    verify(_) ->
        % do nothing

       ok.
```

but I have the same result like the previous code

**what I've done is half of work
remains how to run the program again**

Comment: self() is the pid of the process the test is running on (the shell), not the Pid of your application. Also, killing one process of your application does not guarantee that the whole application will be killed.

Comment: thanks, but how can I have and kill the pid of the application, I have also updated my question

Comment: Looking at the huge list of processes running, and the calls to application_master:start_it/4 it seems that you have at least 2 applications runnings in addition to the default ones (kernel + stdlib). You should use the command application:wich_applications(). to know their names. Then you can stop them with the command application:stop(Appname). You can also restart the application with application:start(Appname).

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to exit the VM in order to restart, you can use the function erlang:halt() or erlang:halt(Status). From the documentation:

> **halt()**
>
> Halts the Erlang runtime system and indicates normal exit to the
>   calling environment. Has no return value.
>
> > **halt().**
> >
> > > os_prompt%
> >
> > **halt(Status)**
> >
> > Types:
> >
> > > **Status = integer() >= 0 | string()**
>
> Status must be a non-negative integer, or a string. Halts the Erlang
>   runtime system. Has no return value. If Status is an integer, it is
>   returned as an exit status of Erlang to the calling environment. If
>   Status is a string, produces an Erlang crash dump with String as
>   slogan, and then exits with a non-zero status code.
>
> Note that on many platforms, only the status codes 0-255 are supported
>   by the operating system.

so your code could be:

```
verify(40) ->
    erlang:halt();
verify(_) ->
    % do nothing
    ok.
```

But as I told you in your previous question, I don't think that you are looking in the good direction.

Comment: thanks for your response, but when I try with this function I have :1>  model:verify(40).
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu/Desktop/erlang#   but I want also run again a program with this command :   ./build.sh && ./deploy.sh && ./erl_start.sh

Comment: The VM stops immediately after the call to erlang:halt/0. You must call the os:cmd function first to have a chance to restart. But beware that doing this, there is a race condition between the 2 instructions! if the os:cmd is fast enough, the VM may have not enough time to stop, and the new VM may fail to start (particularly if you assign it a name via the argument -sname or -name). It is why the good way is to use the option -heart, so the heart program will take care to restart the VM (see http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/heart.html)

Comment: first thank you for your answer, I run my application with this command   ./build.sh && ./deploy.sh && ./erl_start.sh -heart   but how can I change the function verify in order to stop and run again the application ,  as you say we must not use the function : halt